# Looping through Outlook recipients

Tags: c#, outlook

I am trying to loop through shared calendars of outlook recipients and would like some advice. I get the names of the recipients from an ini file and put them into a string.

But when I try to loop through the recipients, it gives me an error. Can you advice me how I can add outlook recipients and loop through them?

```
string CalendarName = iniFile.GetValue("Appointmentdays", "Calendarname");
List<string> names = CalendarName.Split(',').Reverse().ToList();
foreach (var name in names)
{
    //Create Recipient
    Outlook.Recipient recip =  oApp.Session.CreateRecipient(name);
    Outlook.MAPIFolder CalendarFolder = oNS.GetSharedDefaultFolder(recip, Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar);
    String oCalendarName = CalendarFolder.Name;
    String oCalendarEntryID = CalendarFolder.EntryID;
}
```

Comment: Which error do you get?

Comment: Can you please add error details and which line?

Comment: so sorry, I get a null reference error, and it occurs on the line Outlook.Recipient recip =  oApp.Session.CreateRecipient(name);           so I am wondering if I should create a multiple recipient outlook object and then loop through it?

Comment: Is `oApp` equal to `null`? Is `oApp.Session` equal to `null`?

Comment: oApp.Session equal to null; it loops through the first name correctly, the second iteration returns null reference.

Comment: Have you considered using `var bob = oApp.Session;` **before** the loop instead?

Comment: no, what would that do? Sorry I am new to this so please excuse my ignorance

Comment: Well, you said it wasn't `null` the first time, then it was `null` the second time. By doing it outside the loop then inside the loop you can use `bob` - which (according to you) won't be `null` (since it is called only once).

Comment: `foreach (var name in name)` should be `foreach (var name in names)`

Answer (score 0):

If Outlook is not already running, `Application.Session` will be null until you log in, either explicitly, or by doing something that would make Outlook log in. If Outlook is already running, `Namespacee.Logon` would do nothing.

Change your code to

```
    Outlook.Namespacee ns = oApp.GetNamespace("MAPI");
    ns.Logon();
    ...
    Outlook.Recipient recip =  ns.CreateRecipient(name);
```

Answer (score 0):

Eric David

You can use the following code to make sure you have a validity Application object.

```
 Outlook.Application app;
            try
            {
                app = (Outlook.Application)Marshal.GetActiveObject("Outlook.Application");
            }
            catch
            {
                app = new Outlook.Application();
            }

            if (app == null)
            {
                return;
            }
```

Also, the name parameter should be valid.

Please see the following link:[CreateRecipient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.outlook._namespace.createrecipient?view=outlook-pia)